# TFSFieldMapping Access is Denied

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops

Hi I'm am trying to follow Microsoft's guidance to download the TFSFieldMapping file in order that I can make changes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/upload-or-download-the-microsoft-project-mapping-file?view=tfs-2018)

Unfortunately I keep getting the error "Access is denied" when I try to connect to my collection and project

> CD C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\16.0>TFSFieldMapping.exe download /collection:https://dev.azure.com/(My Company) /teamproject:(My Project)/mappingfile:"C:\Users\danie\Downloads\Test1234.xml"
>
> "Access is denied"

Answer (score 1):

That documentation appears to be for TFS (on-premise).  Based on the URL, it looks like you are utilizing Azure DevOps Services.  It seems to be a deprecated function, probably because of the way the field templates have been overhauled for work item forms.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Matt.  TFSFieldMapping is only supports TFS  2018 and previous versions. Because their process is [Hosted XML Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=From%20the%20Process%20page%2C%20open,admin%20to%20grant%20you%20permissions.). Starting from Azure Devops Server 2019 and azure devops service, they use the [inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=From%20the%20Process%20page%2C%20open,admin%20to%20grant%20you%20permissions.). So they doesn't support the TFSFieldMapping.

From the URL in the TFSFieldMapping command, it seems that you are using the Azure Devops Service.

To change the Project field, you can create an inherited process and let the project use it. Then you can perform  custom operations (e.g. Custom field) on the inherited process.

1. You could custom the field in `Organization Settings -> Process`.

Here is a doc about [the detailed steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops).

2. You could also use Rest API to Get and Update the field.

[Get Work item field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/fields?api-version=5.1
```

[Update Work item field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/update?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1):

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/fields/{fieldNameOrRefName}?api-version=4.1
```

**Note:** Corresponding to the inheritance process, you need to inherit first and then customize